# How can I format an hhmmAM/PM (no space) to time hh:mm AM/PM in excel?

Tags: excel, format

I'm working on a payroll project and to make data entry more efficient I want the time entered in a format with hhmmAM/PM, no spaces or colons and preferable just typing a/p instead of AM/PM and have that convert to standard time format with colons and spaces. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small macro that is coded for column **A**.  It can be modified to handle any set of cells.  The macro monitors entries in column **A** and and changes them from values like *0745a* or *0745p* into normal times. Enter the following event macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        s = Target.Text
        If Right(s, 1) = "a" Or Right(s, 1) = "A" Then
            s2 = " AM"
        Else
            s2 = " PM"
        End If
        Target.Value = Left(s, 2) & ":" & Mid(s, 3, 2) & s2
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**