# How can I format an hhmmAM/PM OR hmmAM/PM (no space) to time hh:mm AM/PM in excel?

Tags: excel, formatting

I'm working on a way to make enter timesheets for payroll. I want the time entered in a format with hhmmAM/PM, no spaces or colons and preferable just typing a/p instead of AM/PM and have that convert to standard time format with colons and spaces.

I searched this community and found an answer that gets me most of the way there. The only issue is that this code requires the use of "0" when entering hours example "0545p" converts to "5:45 PM" but "545p" converts to "54:5 PM"

I want to be able to enter 0545p or 545p and still get 5:45 PM

Here is the code I am using:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Application.EnableEvents = False
    s = Target.Text
    If Right(s, 1) = "a" Or Right(s, 1) = "A" Then
        s2 = " AM"
    Else
        s2 = " PM"
    End If
    Target.Value = Left(s, 2) & ":" & Mid(s, 3, 2) & s2
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

End Sub

Source Question: [How can I format an hhmmAM/PM (no space) to time hh:mm AM/PM in excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24373453/how-can-i-format-an-hhmmam-pm-no-space-to-time-hhmm-am-pm-in-excel)

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Check if the left most character is a 1 or a 0 then use the line from above if not then change it to `Target.Value = Left(s, 1) & ":" & Mid(s, 2, 2) & s2`

Comment: Hi, I actually don't know anything about VBE code. The source question gave me instructions on how to copy and past it in. Are you asking me to replace the Target.Value line with the code you just supplied?

Also I was wondering is there a way to make the range more than one column? Example if I wanted column A through D or just columns A and C?

Should it be separate codes for each?

Comment: SO is not a code for me site, so some understanding of vba is expected.  Be careful asking for help on an open forum that you do not understand.  Someone could easily steer you down a path that could harm your computer.

Comment: I apologize for that. I'm still trying to get my head around Superuser/StackOverflow/Stack Exchange. 

This may sound crazy but is there a place to ask questions about where to ask questions? I have 10s of business management questions I want to ask but not sure if there is a place for it.

Basically what I'm getting is that i need to create another if argument to check 1 or 0 and then on the left and if not then put your code. in Just having difficulty figuring out how to make it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my answer... hope this help...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

'Remarks:
'if you want to use another column for your code just to change this
'Range("A:A") to the desire column
'if you want the imput column G then
'Range("G:G") and the new resulting line of code will be
'If Intersect(Target, Range("G:G")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Application.EnableEvents = False
    s = Target.Text
    If Right(s, 1) = "a" Or Right(s, 1) = "A" Then
        s2 = " AM"
    Else
        s2 = " PM"
    End If
    If Left(s, 2) = "11" Or Left(s, 2) = "12" Or Left(s, 2) = "10" Then
        Target.Value = Left(s, 2) & ":" & Mid(s, 3, 2) & s2
    End If
    If Left(s, 1) = "0" Then
        Target.Value = Left(s, 2) & ":" & Mid(s, 3, 2) & s2
    End If
    If Len(s) = 4 Then
        Target.Value = Left(s, 1) & ":" & Mid(s, 2, 2) & s2
    End If
    'the minutes inside the input (545p | 0545p | 500p)
    'always need to be with 2 digits otherwise will return
    'other hour or smonthing like this 54:5 PM then... the formta input is:
    'hmmA/P
    'hhmmA/P
    'if you want to use 24H format would need another implementation
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Tell me if you need something more.

Comment: This seems to work perfectly for everything. I am trying to understand it however. My guess is that the last If Statement for Len(s)=4 is for the 545p option correct? Where we don't put a zero so it returns only one character from the left, adds a semicolon, then 2 characters from the right. 

Why do we need the second If statement ie the one checking for "11", "12" and "10"?