# Formatting hhmmAM/PM (no space) into HH:MM AM/PM and leave cells blank if there is no time entered

Tags: excel, vba, date

My question relates to one from 2014 "[How can I format an hhmmAM/PM (no space) to time hh:mm AM/PM in excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24373453/how-can-i-format-an-hhmmam-pm-no-space-to-time-hhmm-am-pm-in-excel?answertab=votes#tab-top)"

The code that **Gary's Student** suggested does work. However, if there is no time entered in the target cells, the code enters ": PM" and causes #VALUE! errors in the cells that contain calculations elsewhere in the workbook.

Is there something I can add to the code below to say if the Target.Value = ": PM" leave it blank? Thank you.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Application.EnableEvents = False
    s = Target.Text
    If Right(s, 1) = "a" Or Right(s, 1) = "A" Then
        s2 = " AM"
    Else
        s2 = " PM"
    End If
    Target.Value = Left(s, 2) & ":" & Mid(s, 3, 2) & s2
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

End Sub

Answer (score 2):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Application.EnableEvents = False
    s = Target.Text
    If Trim(s) <> "" Then
        If Right(s, 1) = "a" Or Right(s, 1) = "A" Then
            s2 = " AM"
        Else
            s2 = " PM"
        End If
        Target.Value = Left(s, 2) & ":" & Mid(s, 3, 2) & s2
    End If
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Now it will only change the cell if it has text.

Answer (score 1):

Throw this before the `Application.EnableEvents = False line`

```
if Len(Trim(Target.text))=0 then exit sub
```

or add it using an **or** to the intersect line.

Comment: Emphasis on the **BEFORE** the Application.EnableEvents = False line.

Comment: Good call on the trim.